# How to synchronise PDFs annotated externally with Mendeley Desktop

Tags: pdf, mendeley

I'm using Mendeley Desktop to organise PDFs on the cloud which are sync-ed to my Surface Pro. Since Mendeley Desktop is not very touch screen friendly I'm highlighting PDFs with an external program.

However, the highlighted PDFs are not being sync-ed back to the web. Is there any convenient way to push the annotated PDFs up to Mendeley's web storage?

(Currently I have to remove and re-attach the pdf in order for it to be uploaded to the cloud)

Comment: Which external program are you using to highlight your PDFs?

Comment: either Edge or Foxit pdf editor. Either way the annotations are saved in the pdf files themselves.

Comment: I have the same issue. I like to edit with Acrobat Pro, but the synched file is read-only. Mendeley's editor is much less powerful (eg. it has no underline function afaik).